# Structured binding initializer form { assignment-expression } fails for array type on clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++17

[[dcl.dcl]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#1) (final C++17 draft, N4659) describe the grammar of a *simple-declaration* as:

> [...]
>
> simple-declaration:
>   - [...]
>   - *attribute-specifier-seq(opt) decl-specifier-seq ref-qualifier(opt)* [ *identifier-list* ] *initializer*;

[[dcl.dcl]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#8) describes that the latter form of a *simple-declaration* is a structured binding declaration:

> A *simple-declaration* with an *identifier-list* is called a
>   *structured binding declaration* ([dcl.struct.bind]). The *decl-specifier-seq* shall contain only the *type-specifier* `auto` and *cv-qualifier*:s. The *initializer* shall be of the form “=
>   *assignment-expression*”, of the form “{ *assignment-expression* }”, or of the form “( *assignment-expression* )”, where the
>   *assignment-expression* is of array or non-union class type.

I.e., for the purpose of this question, a structured binding have the simplified grammar:

> `auto` [ *identifier-list* ] *initializer* ;

where any of the following forms are valid *initializer*:s:

> ... = *assignment-expression*
>
> ... { *assignment-expression* }
>
> ... ( *assignment-expression* )

Thus, arguably the following code is well-formed:

```
struct S { int s; };

int main() {
    const S s{42};
    const int arr[1] = {42};

    // ... of the form “= assignment-expression”
    auto[s_form1] = s;
    auto[e_form1] = arr;

    // ... of the form “{ assignment-expression }”
    auto[s_form2]{s};
    auto[e_form2]{arr};

    // ... of the form “( assignment-expression )”
    auto[s_form3](s);
    auto[e_form3](arr);

    (void)s_form1; (void)s_form2; (void)s_form3;
    (void)e_form1; (void)e_form2; (void)e_form3;

    return 0;
}
```

Using both `-std=c++17` and `-std=c++2a`, GCC (9.3) accepts this code whereas clang (10.0.0 as well as HEAD/11) rejects the "{ *assignment-expression* }" form for arrays:

> ```
> auto[e_form2]{arr};
>               ^~~
> error: cannot initialize an array element of type 'const int'
>        with an lvalue of type 'const int [1]'
> ```

It fails likewise for an rvalue array:

> ```
> using SingleElementIntArray = int[1];
> auto[e_form2]{SingleElementIntArray{42}};
>               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> error: cannot initialize an array element of type
>        'int' with an rvalue of type 
>        'SingleElementIntArray' (aka 'int [1]')
> ```

#### Question

- Who is right here, GCC or clang? My guess is GCC; if so, is this a known clang bug?

Comment: This is [llvm bug 32466](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32466).

Comment: @Barry There's the bug report, thanks! Feel free to make your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is a known bug, with an open bug report

LLVM open bug report:

- [Bug 32466 - Clang doesn't support structured binding of initializer form {" expr }" for array](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32466)

> Ryou Ezoe 2017-03-30 00:24:07 PDT:
>
> Clang doesn't support structured binding of initializer form {" expr
>   }" if expr is id-expression of array object.   Clang does not accept
>   following code.
>
> ```
> int expr[] = { 1,2,3 } ;
> auto [a,b,c]{expr} ;
> ```
>
> with the error:
>
> > prog.cc:4:18: error: cannot initialize an array
> >     element of type 'int' with an lvalue of type 'int [3]'
>
> Other cases are works as expected. "( expr  )" works as well as "{
>   expr }" where expr is id-expression of class object:
>
> ```
> auto [a,b,c](expr) ;
>
> struct X { int x,y,z } ; 
> X x {1,2,3} ; 
> auto [a,b,c]{ x } ;
> ```